# Como fazer uma requisição [GET] com custom headers no Angular 10?

Tags: angular, http-request

Preciso fazer uma chamada para meu microserviço em angular 10, passando algumas informações no Header da requisição. Porém, ao fazer isso, retorna o seguinte erro:

### Erro disparado no console ao executar a chamada do serviço

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field filtertype is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

---

Preciso configurar algo no meu microserviço? Fiz a mesma chamada pelo postman, e funciona. Mas pela minha aplicação angular, não funciona. Mesmo eu deployando e testando em PROD também não funciona.
Já tentei montar o cabeçalho de várias formas, mas todas acabam no mesmo erro. Segue o código:
***(Notem que a requisição não funciona quando passo os custom headers)***

**Tentativa Nº 1 ->> FUNCIONA**

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', accessToken)
 
return this.http.get(`${API_URL}`, { headers }).pipe(map((data: any) => { 
   return data;
});
```

---

**Tentativa Nº 2 ->> NÃO FUNCIONA**

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', accessToken)
        .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')
        .append('access-control-allow-origin', '*')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
        .append('filterType', 'name')
        .append('size', size.toString());

return this.http.get(`${API_URL}`, { headers }).pipe(map((data: any) => { 
   return data;
});
```

---

**Tentativa Nº 3 ->> NÃO FUNCIONA**

```
 var config = {
    headers:  {
      'Authorization': accessToken,
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      'filterType': "name",
      "size" : size.toString()
    }
  };

return this.http.get(`${API_URL}`, config).pipe(map((data: any) => { 
   return data;
});
```

Comment: Quando isso aconteceu comigo, era um erro no backend, teve que ser feita uma modificação no backend para o tipo de acesso CORS ser permitido.

Comment: Você pode remover os dois cabeçalhos de CORS `access-control-allow-origin` e `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` pois eles são cabeçalhos de resposta, não de requisição. Onde o servidor vai responder com eles para o navegador saber se deve ou não permitir a requisição

Comment: Realmente precisava modificar o server para aceitar esses headers "custom". Então optei por mandar a informação de outra forma. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Muitas vezes quando acontece erro de CORS ele é disparado pelo backend. Você precisaria adionar [Access-Cross-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) no backend.

Se estiver utilizando nodejs com express, existe um pacote simples para liberar o acesso.

1. Instale o pacote: `npm install cors`
2. Adicione logo após instanciar o express:

```
    var express = require('express')
    var cors = require('cors')
    var app = express()
    app.use(cors())
```

Para adicionar mais configurações no cors veja o [pacote npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .append('Authorization', accessToken)
    .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')
    .append('access-control-allow-origin', '*')
    .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
    .append('filterType', 'name')
    .append('size', size.toString());

return this.http.get(`${API_URL}`, { headers: headers }).pipe(map((data: any) => { 
   return data;
});
```

No momento de passar os Headers dentro dos options prescrisa ser passado como um objeto: {headers: HttpHeaders}

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo. Mas também não funcionou :/